# Something in my Preferences file breaks auto-complete

Tags: java, eclipse

There's something in my preferences file that is causing Eclipse's auto-complete feature (for Java) to not work.

What do I mean? Well, I work on multiple computers, and I like a very specific color scheme. So, I exported my preferences file from Eclipse on one computer, and I import it to Eclipse on my other computers. The colors look great and everything is nice.

The problem is, something about the importing of the preferences file is causing auto-complete to stop working. This has happened several times, but to figure it out I did the following: I got a fresh copy of Eclipse 3.6. Auto-complete works. Then I import the preferences file, and auto-complete stops working. The suggestion contains no entries.

Here's a picture to make it all real for you:
[image]
<sub>(source: [nelsbeckman.com](http://www.nelsbeckman.com/pictures/no_auto_complete.png))</sub>

This is kind of annoying. Any ideas what could be causing this? I really only care about my font and the colors in the preferences file... If you want to look at the file, I keep it [here on Google Code](https://code.google.com/archive/p/nolacoaster/source).

Thanks,
Nels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience Eclipse preferences only work well within the same minor version (3.4, 3.5, 3.6 etc) and you go from 3.5 to 3.6.

I would take the time to rebuild your preference setup and generate a new preferences file for using with 3.6.

Comment: Okay, well I was afraid of this BUT now I have the motivation to go back and pare it down to just the essentials. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might have the "Java Proposals" unchecked in Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced.

I think it happened to me once because of Mylyn, which activates it's own "Java Proposals (Tasks-Focused)" instead. When I imported the preferences into a new Eclipse installation that didn't have Mylyn installed, I no longer had any completions.